# How to install a symbolic link to one of two installed executables?

Tags: autotools

EDIT: I may not have been clear originally.

> At "make install" I want the installing user to be able to set a symbolic link, "hello", that links to either a prog that's statically linked, "helloStatic," or a prog that's dynamically linked, "helloShared." See my answer.

I currently build and install:

- HelloShared, which is my main.o linked to my shared library libsay.la
- HelloStatic, which is my main.o linked to my static library libsay.a

I'd also like to install Hello, which would be a symbolic link to either HelloShared or HelloStatic.

I'm guessing that choice would be made by providing an option to either configure or make?

I'm mainly concerned with *nix or cygwin, although how to do it in a Windows install would be nice too.

Recap, I want the two built executables installed, and in addition a symbolic link to the executable that the installing person wants to be the "normal" version. Ideally also a default link if none is chosen.

Started with some source files, I created a configure.ac with autoscan, and then built that up as necessary.

My workflow is:

- autorconf -i
- ./configure
- make

After make I get:

```
$ file hello*
helloShared: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable, with very long lines
helloStatic: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=f56d94fbc40359aced749759231d3e7ae39587a0, not stripped
```

My files:

```
$ tree -a
├── configure.ac
├── lib
│   ├── say.c
│   └── say.h
├── m4
├── Makefile.am
└── src
    └── main.c

3 directories, 5 files

##########

$ cat configure.ac
#                                               -*- Autoconf -*-
# Process this file with autoconf to produce a configure script.

AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT([Hello], [0.1])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([lib/say.h])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])

AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([build-aux])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign subdir-objects -Wall -Werror])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])

AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS([m4])

# Checks for programs.
AC_PROG_CC
AM_PROG_AR

LT_INIT

# Checks for libraries.

# Checks for header files.

# Checks for typedefs, structures, and compiler characteristics.

# Checks for library functions.

AC_OUTPUT

##########

$ cat Makefile.am
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4

pkglib_LTLIBRARIES = libsay.la
libsay_la_SOURCES = \
    lib/say.c

libsay_la_CFLAGS = -I lib

pkglib_LIBRARIES = libsay.a
libsay_a_SOURCES = \
    lib/say.c

libsay_a_CFLAGS = -I lib

include_HEADERS = \
    lib/say.h

bin_PROGRAMS = helloShared helloStatic

helloShared_SOURCES = \
    src/main.c
helloShared_CFLAGS = -I lib
helloShared_LDADD = libsay.la

helloStatic_SOURCES = \
    src/main.c
helloStatic_CFLAGS = -I lib
helloStatic_LDADD = libsay.a
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a target

```
install-exec-hook:
       ln whatever
```

An example in the documentation:
https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Extending

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution (at the moment) to my own question. I'm not marking it as accepted, because:

- I'm not sure if "?=" is portable across different makes.
- It feels kind of fallback-ish.
- I don't know if there's a more autotoolish way to do it.

configure.ac:

```
AC_PROG_LN_S
```

Makefile.am:

```
LINK_HELLO_TO ?= helloStatic

install-exec-hook:
    (cd ${bindir}; $(LN_S) $(LINK_HELLO_TO) hello)

uninstall-hook:
    (cd ${bindir}; rm -f hello)
```

Development workflow:

```
$ autoreconf

$ ./configure

$ make

$ sudo make install # Accept default sym link.

# Or explicitly set default:

$ sudo make install LINK_HELLO_TO=helloStatic

# Or set to link to executable that links to shared lib.

$ sudo make install LINK_HELLO_TO=helloShared

$ ll -gGF /usr/local/bin/hello*
lrwxrwxrwx 1   11 Feb 19 20:40 /usr/local/bin/hello -> helloShared*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 9.5K Feb 19 20:40 /usr/local/bin/helloShared*
-rwxr-xr-x 1  12K Feb 19 20:40 /usr/local/bin/helloStatic*
```